# Javascript, cookie clicker counter not updating

Tags: javascript, html, counter

Ive just started learning js and im trying to make a basic cookie clicker but I just cant figure out why the counter on the page isnt updating.

```
<body>

    <div id="header">COOKIE CLICKER</div>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="counter">
                <div id="countertext">
                    <a id="cookieCount">0 Cookies</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="cookie">
                <a href>
                    <img id="cookieImage" src="images\cookie.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="upgrade">UPGRADE</div>
        </div>

</body>
<script src="cookie.js"></script> 
</html>
```

```
var cookieCount = document.getElementById('cookieCount');
var cookieCount = 0;
var cookieImage = document.getElementById('cookieImage');

// cookieImage.addEventListener('click', oneClick);



cookieImage.onClick = function() {
    cookieCount++;
    cookieCount.innerHTML = cookieCount + "Cookies";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your HTML document should have an `<html>` open tag. 
I created an example that works for me, and I replaced the image with a button just to demonstrate.

The `index.html` file:

```
<html>                                                                                  
<body>                                                                                  
    <div id="header">COOKIE CLICKER</div>                                               
        <div id="container">                                                            
            <div id="counter">                                                          
                <div id="countertext">                                                  
                    <a id="cookieCount">0 Cookies</a>                                   
                </div>                                                                  
            </div>                                                                      
            <button id="cookieImage">                                                   
                Click                                                                   
            </button>                                                                   
            <div id="upgrade">UPGRADE</div>                                             
        </div>                                                                          
</body>                                                                                 
<script src="cookie.js"></script>-                                                      
</html>
```

The `cookie.js` file:

```
var cookieCount = document.getElementById('cookieCount');                               
var count = 0;                                                                          
var cookieImage = document.getElementById('cookieImage');                               


function onClick() {                                                                  
    count++;                                                                            
    cookieCount.innerHTML = count + " Cookies";                                         
};                                                                                      

cookieImage.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

The problem in your `cookie.js` has been that you used the `cookieCount` variable twice.

Comment: Thanks! I have an opening <html> tag but i didnt bother including all that html info, I was sure there wasn't a problem there. And that js code adds to the counter but it resets after a frame, how do i get it to stay on the screen?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean with after a frame, but if you mean that you want to keep the count after you reload the page you can use the local storage or cookies.

You can find a tutorial on how to use the local storage here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp